# How can I show only specific block from post on front page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating a custom header block for a theme. It generates a special layout out of three different images and text. When a post contains this block it should only show this block on the front page. I found a solution that works but seems dirty and also I would like to encapsulate this within the block plugin and not the theme.

Current solution in theme (in content.php):

```
$content = get_the_content();

if( !is_frontpage() && has_blocks( $content ) ) {

  $blocks = parse_blocks( $content );

  if ( !empty($blocks) && $blocks[0]['blockName'] === 'namespace/block' ) {
    echo $blocks[0]['innerHTML'];
  }
  else {
    the_content();
  }
}
```

I also tried to integrate it within the plugin file:

```
function namespace_block_frontpage_blocks($content) {
  if( is_front_page() && has_blocks( $content ) ) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks( $content );
    if ( !empty($blocks) && $blocks[0]['blockName'] === 'namespace/block' ) {
      return $blocks[0]['innerHTML'];
    }
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','namespace_block_frontpage_blocks' );
```

But this doesn't work since 'has_blocks' returns false and 'parse_blocks' doesn't return anything.

**UPDATE**

I found a solution. You need to give the add_filter function a priority (third parameter):

```
add_filter( 'the_content','namespace_block_frontpage_blocks', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done via CSS: The homepage in Wordpress has the `home` class in its `body` tag, so if your block's class for example is `.my_block_1`, you can write this into the stylesheet:

```
.my_block_1 {
  display: none;
}
.home .my_block_1 {
  display: block;
}
```

That will hide that block on all pages except the homepage.

Comment: Hi Johannes. Unfortunately, I meant the opposite. Hide all other blocks besides the first block on the frontpage. I could of course also do this with css, but this would result in the whole post being loaded on the frontpage...